# Want to make the script send email only to the last added one in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a script to send emails to the contacts I saved in googlespreadsheets. However, I want it only to send it to the last added email (not all the list). It keeps sending it to everyone included in the list and I want only to send to the last added email in row[2] where are the emails registered.

Thanks.

```
 function sendEmail(e) {
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
      var data = ws.getRange("A2:D" +ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
      data.forEach(function(row) {
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlemail.html")
      var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
      var subject = "Thanks for participation";
      var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it.";
      var options = { htmlBody : htmlText };
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[2], subject, textBody, options);
      });
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I want it only to send it to the last added email (not all the list).`. Especially, I cannot understand `the last added email`. Can I ask you about the situation the email is added to Spreadsheet?

Comment: Apology for my bad English. What I meant is that I want the script only send it to the newest email added to the row (not all the previous ones).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could notice that your issue had been resolved just now. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only email the last row every time.

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlemail.html")
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  var subject = "Thanks for participation";
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it.";
  var options = { htmlBody : htmlText };
  GmailApp.sendEmail(data[data.length-1][2], subject, textBody, options);
}
```

if you do it this way then it will only use that line once unless you edit it with additional emails.

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlemail.html")
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  var subject = "Thanks for participation";
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it.";
  var options = { htmlBody : htmlText };
  if(data[data.length-1][2]) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(data[data.length-1][2], subject, textBody, options);
    ws.getRange(data.length-1+2,3).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this: `I want only to send to the last added email in row[2] where are the emails registered.`  What does `where are the emails registered.` mean?

Comment: Apology for my bad English. What I meant is that I want the script only send it to the newest email added to the row (not all the previous ones).

Comment: Well take you pick.  There are two choice one will send the last row every time and one will send the last row one time.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your answer. You're so kind. Thanks for your answer.